# how to choose the design pattern in java

Tags: java, security

i have a project to be done which on the domain of healthcare, so what design pattern would be used or should be used because the system should be strong enough so that no hacker find a way to hack or steal the information.

```
the following technology is used
1.struts 1.2.9
2.mysql for backend
3.spring security.
```

so please suggest me the best design for this and the sample if possible since i have never worked with design pattern.

So please help me to achieve this

Regards.

Comment: `no hacker find a way to hack or steal the information` in an ideal world...

Comment: may be true but should not allow unauthorized, access to anybody to the system, by the way thanks for the comment but not useful to the question asked

Comment: What you need to start off with is the architecture of the system; design pattern would come later when you start cocneptualizing/ designing the actual modules within the system. In any case your question as of now is too broadly described

Comment: There is no "pattern" as such since we do not know who should have access. Will it be only internal personal or should "patients" be able to login or will there be public statistics, webservices, intregrations with other systems.

Comment: Patients will have access to his/her information only and doctors also the same

Comment: This is basically a security question, nothing to do with design patterns at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General guidelines for a secure system. (Not complete, just my own observations)

Never trust information, even if you just read it from the database, do not assume it is 100 % safe to store back in always verify it is safe (no sql or script injections).

Do not separate checking from storing, you never know when someone will copy paste the code missing the verification step, try to make the storing in a way that aborts without the check.

Never trust obscurity, always verify permissions and data.

Use a consistent solution for permissions so no ambiguity can exist on how a permission should be checked.

Think carefully on who need access and avoid loading information that should not be present and that is not needed, if it is not in memory it will be more difficult to gain access to.

Use separate data retrieval layer with built in permission checking so that it is harder to get data by hacking the first client layer.

Consider the risk in several steps, storing a script tag in the database might be safe but what damage could that script cause if loaded into a page in a valid session.

Verify any ajax calls, injected javascript (could come from viruses in the client computer or plugins), could otherwise send commands that your own page would never send, and send them in the context of the user.

And look for books on how to build secure systems, no post here will cover everything and no book will replace experience and planing.

And live by the rule, there is no secure system, only hard enough to crack.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have misunderstood the term design pattern.

Design patterns are commonly used generic or "template" (beware, that is a bad word, as it is also used in design pattern name) code solutions, that are fit for a generic problem (Object **creation**, Inheritance **structure**, and object **behaviour**) in an object oriented programming environment to enhance reusability in a language agnostic way.

There is no design pattern to ensure a system is not hackable - there are best practices for each language, but outside of strictly programming, there are a lot of other aspects to secure a system. Like you can employ the highest level of encription to achieve nothing, when your root password is still the default one...

Answer (score 2):

As others already mentioned: Start with your architecture!
Especially figure out,

-which states your application can have, how to support the programmer that only the allowed states are reached (state-transition-modelling)

- how to validate incoming requests
- how to find illegal accesses
- How to protect your application itself(webserver, ...)

Design-Patterns will help you, when you do the daily work, but can't protect you from security-holes in the architecture.
And the architecure will give you a lot of hints, which design-patterns make sense.

At least about one thing I would think about: Stuts 1.2.9. It's not the newest version (means not the savest) and struts itself has some architecture-problems with security.
When you use spring, why not using other, more modern compontents there too?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague.  Giving us a list of your main components and asking us to come up with the "best design"...  Could you give us (a lot) more details, please?